# How was the neutron's spin measured?

Tags: experimental-physics, quantum-spin, neutrons, precession

In 2012 it was asked, [How to measure the spin of a neutral particle](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/8530/how-to-measure-the-spin-of-a-neutral-particle). I'm not sure that the answer "Neutron spin can be measured in a Stern Gerlach setup." was really carried out. So what for techniques are required to measure the spin of a neutron?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The spin of the neutron *was* measured by the [Stern-Gerlach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Gerlach_experiment) experiment by [Sherwood, Stephenson and Bernstein (1954)](http://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.96.1546) (sadly paywalled, free links welcome),

> **Abstract**: A neutron beam was polarized by total reflection from a magnetized iron mirror. The beam was then analyzed by passing it through an inhomogeneous magnetic field. From the deflection pattern obtained, it is inferred that the resultant neutron spin in the polarized beam was parallel to the magnetic field applied to the mirror. Thus the nuclear and magnetic scattering amplitudes for iron are of the same sign when the neutron spin and electronic spin are oppositely directed, and conversely.

So the techniques would be the same for any other Stern-Gerlach apparatus. Note that [neutral particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutral_particle) will still have an [intrinsic magnetic moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_moment), so the Stern-Gerlach experiment would result in the split pattern.

Comment: Interesting. I know they are fermions but I am a bit surprised to learn that they interact with magnetic fields. I never really thought about it. How would this interaction be characterized by the standard model?

Comment: The spin was only parallel and not anti parallel too to the magnetic field? So the deflection from the magnetic field was in one direction only?

Comment: What do you mean *How would this interaction be characterized by the standard model*? AFAIK, QM & SM are **not** at odds with each other, so asking if they're in conflict seems very strange.

Comment: And the spin appears to be aligned parallel/anti-parallel to the magnetic field so the deflection would be either up or down (relating to the spin of the particle); that's kinda how the SG experiment works.

Comment: This link describes a Stern-Gerlach experiment applied to potassium, but it seems to be an accessible and easy-to-understand account of the procedure and its significance: http://people.roma2.infn.it/~carboni/SternGerlach.pdf

Comment: "And the spin appears to be aligned parallel/anti-parallel..." This is it what is needed to see that neutron has a spin too. Unfortunately this is not described in the Abstracts.

Comment: a link to the paper from  Sherwood, Stephenson and Bernstein (1954) https://dtk.tankonyvtar.hu/xmlui/bitstream/handle/123456789/8932/B9780123956897500139.pdf?sequence=13&isAllowed=y